# compare binary files and print only offset of matching line

Tags: linux, diff, binaryfiles, cmp, comm

For regular files I can use the `comm` command to find common lines.

For example we have two files

```
$ cat f1
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5

$ cat f2
line1
line20
line30
line4
line5
```

Its compared like:

```
$ comm -12 f1 f2
line1
line4
line5
```

How to find the offset of matching lines and also how to do comparison for two binary files and print matching line offset?

I've been using things like `diff`, `cmp`, `comm` for past 1hr, unable to figure this out.

EDIT 1:
Not exact solution but found vbindiff it helps a bit.

Comment: If it's a binary file, it doesn't have lines.

Comment: okay, right, but how to figure out offset of first common 80chars within these files.

Comment: I understand your question but not your problem. What do you really want to achieve? Which problem you want to solve?

Comment: I have two files which are binary dump (unknown format). Say file1 has content "abcde" and file2 has "defgh" . I need to figure out a way to merge these two files by removing the common pattern. in this case its "de". output will be "abcdefgh"

Answer (score 9):

You are probably looking for `cmp`:

> cmp - compare two files byte by byte

```
$ cmp f1 f2
f1 f2 differ: byte 12, line 2

$ cmp -b f1 f2
f1 f2 differ: byte 12, line 2 is  12 ^J  60 0

$ cmp -bl f1 f2
12  12 ^J    60 0
13 154 l     12 ^J
14 151 i    154 l
15 156 n    151 i
16 145 e    156 n
17  63 3    145 e
18  12 ^J    63 3
19 154 l     60 0
20 151 i     12 ^J
21 156 n    154 l
22 145 e    151 i
23  64 4    156 n
24  12 ^J   145 e
25 154 l     64 4
26 151 i     12 ^J
27 156 n    154 l
28 145 e    151 i
29  65 5    156 n
30  12 ^J   145 e
cmp: EOF on f1
```

From `man cmp`:

> **-b**, --print-bytes
>
> print differing bytes
>
> **-l**, --verbose
>
> output byte numbers and differing byte values

Comment: thanks,Does cmp has option which will print matching line/byte offset? instead of telling about differ byte

Comment: As they are treated as binary, there is no such concept of lines. I am not very sure about how you expect the output to look like, could you clarify?

Comment: I would like to figure out which offset they have common pattern. For example something like : cmp f1 f2
f1 f2 same at byte byte 120, line 12 . Thanks for the help, for my case, I found "vbindiff".

Comment: I insist: there is no such thing like line in binary files. As you can see, `cmp` shows a message like "f1 f2 differ: byte 12, line 2 is  12 ^J  60 0"